Central stage mode not working in swift iOS app. AVFoundation framework
I am working on an iPad app using the front camera. The camera logic is implemented using the AVFoundation framework. During a session I use central stage mode to center the face. Central stage mode works fine in all cases except when I set the session preset photo. In other presets: high,  medium, low, cif352x288, vga640x480, hd1280x720, hd1920x1080, iFrame960x540, iFrame1280x720, inputPriority central stage mode working  except photo session preset. Can you explain why this happens or maybe it is an unobvious bug?
Code example:
 func setupCamera() {
        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) else { return }
        AVCaptureDevice.centerStageControlMode = .app
        AVCaptureDevice.isCenterStageEnabled = true
        
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
            captureSession.addInput(input)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
            captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
            
        } catch {
            print("Error setting up camera: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

I wrote to Apple developers support but didn't receive a response, looks like their bug.
